# MailKit not connecting in Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mailkit

I am using https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit for my Unity game project
I could import all needed packages and dependencies to my project successfully.
I did this for other NuGet packages such as AWSSDK for .NET and I am sure this could not be a problem.
[image]

This is the tutorial I followed
https://blog.christian-schou.dk/send-emails-with-asp-net-core-with-mailkit/

```cs
public async Task<bool> SendAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize a new instance of the MimeKit.MimeMessage class
        var mail = new MimeMessage();

        mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "myemail@gmail.com"));
        mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "reciever@gmail.com"));
        mail.Subject = "Hello from Mailkit!";
        mail.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "This is the body of the email."
        };

        using var smtp = new SmtpClient();

        {
            await smtp.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            //await smtp.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        }
        await smtp.AuthenticateAsync("myemail@gmail.com", "app-password-from-google-account");
        await smtp.SendAsync(mail);
        await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true);

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But tried this again and again and I got this error continuously

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
MailkitSmtpTester/<SendAsync>d__3:MoveNext () (at 
Assets/Scenes/MailkitSmtpTester.cs:86)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks ()`
```

I tried to do some trouble shooting

- Check your internet connection: Ensure that you have a stable internet connection. Try accessing other websites or services to verify if your connection is working properly.
- Verify the SMTP server settings: Double-check the SMTP server settings you are using in your Mailkit code. Make sure you have the correct server address, port number, and authentication credentials.
- Check firewall and antivirus settings: Sometimes, firewalls or antivirus software can block outgoing connections. Temporarily disable any firewall or antivirus software and test if the issue persists. If the error disappears, you may need to configure your security software to allow the Mailkit application to establish a connection.
- Test with a different network: If possible, try running your code on a different network or internet connection. This will help determine if the issue is specific to your current network configuration.
- Verify server availability: Ensure that the SMTP server you are trying to connect to is up and running. You can check the server status by pinging the server or contacting your email service provider.
- Check for any IP blocking: It's possible that your IP address has been blocked by the SMTP server due to suspicious activity. Contact your email service provider to check if your IP address is blocked and request removal if necessary.

So I turned off firewall and allow all connection from 465 and 587 port in inbound and outbound of my VPS
But still got the same error
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please edit your title to be meaningful and specific. Doesn't matter how many times you've tried something (that should be removed)

Comment: have a look at the related questions.  One says that MailKit is blocked on the gmail side (NOT your ISP but on Google's end) and the other says it was an issue w/ the MailKit version and downgrading to 2.0.0 worked from them

Comment: @sous2817 the reason 1 user had to downgrade to MailKit v2.0.0 is because one of the later 2.x versions of MailKit had tried to simplify the Connect() logic by using Socket.Connect(string host, int port) rather than doing the DNS lookups and then attempting to connect to the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses sequentially. This is because Socket.Connect() chooses IPv6 and, if that fails, stubbornly refuses to fall back to IPv4 which is what the internet at large uses. This was subsequently fixed in a newer 2.x version of MailKit and has remained fix throughout v3.x and v4.x

Comment: @James Something is clearly blocking connections from your client machine to smtp.gmail.com and preventing the SmtpClient from establishing a connection. I see that you changed your firewall software to allow connections, but your antivirus software could be blocking connections as well. It's also possible, if you are behind a NAT, that your NAT is also blocking connections. You could try writing code to connect a System.Net.Sockets.Socket to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 (don't need to worry about SSL handshakes, just try to connect) and seeing if that also fails.

Comment: Could I use other smtp hosting servers, for example an outlook server instead of goggle? @sous2817

Comment: I imported the most recent package from NuGet gallery.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/
You are saying that should I downgrade to v2.0.0? @jstedfast

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/2.0.0#dependencies-body-tab
Should I downgrade to this ? the 12/22/2017 version? @jstedfast

Comment: I tried to connect a System.Net.Sockets.Socket to smtp.gmail.com on port 46
And also failed. This means it would also fail even after downgrading to v2.0.0?
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Downgraded to v2.0.0 and still got the same error
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: I would go with whatever @jstedfast recommends.  I'm just some random guy on the internet, he knows what he's talking about.  Upgrade to the latest version of MailKit and follow his comment above.

Comment: connection to smtp-mail.outlook.com is the same

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842428/gmail-smtp-failure-using-c-sharp-smtpclient

also note in the answer about using a less secure app access.  

Again, I have no idea just googling on your behalf

Comment: Hi @James, no, I did not mean for you to downgrade to MailKit 2.0.0. The bug that existed in the other StackOverflow question has been fixed for several years at this point. When you tried to connect a socket to smtp.gmail.com, did you use port 46 or port 465? I just want to make sure you used port 465 because port 46 is probably not configured to respond to connection requests and would therefore fail, giving us a false indication.

Comment: @James, for clarification, are you running this program locally on your development machine? Or is this failing when running on a remote server such as AWS or Azure or something? If locally on your development machine, is your computer connected to a router? Is it possible that the router has a firewall set up?

Comment: Thank you for your advice @jstedfast
I used port 465 and I downgraded to v2.0.0
I am running the code on my remote server (Cloudzy VPS https://cloudzy.com/)
I turned off the firewall and allowed the ports (465, 587) in inbound and outbound rules.
Thank you

Comment: I tried all things what I could do
Same error with smtp-mail.outlook.com
I think there maybe unknown blocking between my VPS and smtp servers
Thank you @jstedfast How could we find out the blocking thing?

Comment: Contact Cloudzy and ask for help figuring out why you can’t connect to any mail server.